# Retrieving data from MYSQL based on week number

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date, select

I am having a table as follows in MYSQL:

```
proj_id|hoursWorked|Date.
```

The date field is of type `Date`; I want to retrieve all the entries from a table depending on a given week number for the project in my java based web application. Please help me to achieve this.

I am unable to write a single query that will allow me to do so.

Comment: What queries have you tried? Did you see the MySQL documentation on this topic?

Comment: i have tried to use the subtract function on dates.

Answer (score 5):

Do **not** use  something like `WHERE WEEK(column)=something` - this is a performance killer: It will calculate the week number on all rows, even if they don't match. In addition to that it will make it impossible to use an index ont this column.

Instead calculate an absolute begin and end date or point in time, depending on your data type, then use `BETWEEN`. This will do no calculations on non-matching rows and allow the use of an index.

Rule of thumb: If you have the choice between a calculation on a constant and on a field, use the former.

Comment: Means to say u suggest that i must find start date and end date for a given week number and then use between fot these dates to get data for given week number.please correct me if i have got u wrong?

Comment: That is exactly what I ment. I am not familiar with the Java base class library, but all environments I am familiar with do have functions to perform this in a few lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

Use [WEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)

```
select * from your_table
where week(`Date`) = week('2012-12-01')
```

If you want to get only records from the current week you can do

```
select * from your_table
where week(`Date`) = week(curdate())
```

Comment: The week number will be relative to a given date, say for example start date of project in this case.

Comment: You can use any date you like and extract the week from that. See my update.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the year along with the week? for example I have data from both 2012 and 2013 and while making the selection I need records only from 2013.
   `select * from my_table where week(Date)=2013-50` can I do something similar to this ??

Comment: @GovindKailas: [**YEARWEEK()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek)

Comment: @juergen it doesn't seems to be working
`select * from my_table where yearweek(Date)=201350`

Comment: Np , I got it, I missed to put the yearweek in quotes. `select * from my_table where yearweek(Date)='201350'`

Answer (score 2):

use MySQL `WEEK()` function.

```
SELECT WEEK(dateColumn)
FROM...
WHERE WEEK(dateColumn) = 1
```

- [WEEK()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)

from MySQL Docs

> This function returns the week number for date. The two-argument form
>   of WEEK() enables you to specify whether the week starts on Sunday or
>   Monday and whether the return value should be in the range from 0 to
>   53 or from 1 to 53.

Comment: How to use Week() function if i am computing the week number relative to some fixed date.

Comment: try, `WHERE WEEK(dateColumn) = WEEK(CURDATE())`

Comment: @JW Dont you agree with what EugenRieck has specified above in his answer? Just a quick question for better understanding.

Comment: @BhavikShah I certainly agree as using functions around columnNames kills the index. `:D`

Comment: @JW then i guess, EugenRieck's answer is better in terms of performance and speed. Thanks for reply. Merry Christmas.